# Create a workflow for a list that will trigger depending on the item author

Tags: 2010, workflow

I'm trying to create a WF that will be associated with a list and trigger every time a specific user creates a new item for that list.
So basically I need to run a workflow automatically depending on the value of a list item, how  I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You run workflow every time new item is added and on start you check author field. If author is desired one you go ahead and if not you stop.

This is general concept. You will need to provide more info if you desire more detailed instructions eg. are you using Sharepoint Designer or Visual Studio to build your workflow?

Edited:

Sharepoint Designer first step:

Check if author is in group Approvers (change condition to meet your requirements). If Author is not in group Approver - workflow stops.
[image]

Comment: I'm using Sharepoing Designer to create it and it's based on the out of the box Approval Workflow, where and how exactly do i check the author field? thanks

Comment: I have updated my answer

Comment: How would I use this if i wanted to compare the Created By value to a custom list (of users) on my site?

Comment: It would be difficult and maybe even not possible. It really depends on your specific requirements. After you insert `IF decision` in your workflow step, click value, select `Workflow Lookup for a User` and explore possibilities.

Comment: Yeah I have been doing that with no luck, tried using a permissions group such as 'site Members' with no luck, thanks a lot anyway